# Writing high bytes in Intel Hex file to PIC 16F886 using MiniPro TL866A

Tags: pic, programming, hex-file

I'm a newbie trying to write an Intel hex file to a PIC 16F886 using a MiniPro TL866A. When I try, I get the message:

```
$ minipro -p PIC16F886 -f ihex -w downloaded-file.hex
Found TL866A 03.2.86 (0x256)
Chip ID OK: 0x2062 Rev.0x2060
Found Intel hex file.
Incorrect file size: 3145742 (needed 16384)
```

Looking at the hex file in the [parser at Nordic Semiconductor](https://nordicsemiconductor.github.io/nrf-intel-hex/demo.html), I can see that there are two parts that are outside the range of the PIC:

```
Block starting at 2097152 (0x200000), 8 (0x8) bytes long
Block starting at 3145728 (0x300000), 14 (0xe) bytes long
```

What are these 8 and 14-byte values, and how do I write them to the PIC?

Comment: You may need to consult the source of the file.  I believe I once saw a local tradition of putting fuse settings at implausible addresses in a file to keep them associated with the code, but such a scheme only works if the user of the file shares that tradition.

Comment: The ID and configuration bits for that chip are supposed to be at 0x2000-2003 and 0x2007-0x2008 which is already outside the program memory space. What's the hex file saying should be in those very high locations?  Where did the file come from?

Comment: This is what's in my file: :020000040020DA
:08000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00
:020000040030CA
:0E000000FF38193CFF3580FF08800FE00F40ED. The file came from an antenna tuner manufacturer who no longer supports the model I have with the bad PIC.

Answer (score 2):

Microchip assembler seems to set the configuration and ID locations using those very high addresses. For example, from the [manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/33014K.pdf):

[image]

So it appears there is some incompatibility between the third-party programmer and Microchip's hex files. Maybe you can update the programmer firmware, or if it's an illegal clone use some tool like a Pickit.

Comment: The problem was indeed the MiniPro TL866A programmer. Even using the latest firmware available, it had issues - apparently this isn't uncommon. Switching to a PICKit 2 and using Microchip's pk2cmd, I was able to write just fine.